# Capture photo by pressing beacon device click

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8.2

I am new to iOS development. I am working on an App where the user can open camera by clicking beacon device button. I also want to take a photo by clicking beacon device rather than camera default controls.
How can I do with beacon device.here is code of open camera but cannot capture photo by pressing beacon device click

```
- (void)doublePressNotify:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CBPeripheral *peripheral = notification.object;
    AXATag *tag = [self findAXATag:peripheral.identifier.UUIDString];
    tag.pressType = @"double press";
    tag.beaconuuid = peripheral.identifier.UUIDString;
    NSLog(@"Shaheryar: %@", tag.beaconuuid);
    if([tag.beaconuuid  isEqual: @"B5F38CEB-C002-4A35-95BE-031F756131C4"]) {

        if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

            UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Device has no camera" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [myAlertView show];

        } else {

            UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.allowsEditing = YES;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Camera not working when you try to capture?

Comment: camera is working but i want to capture photo by pressing beacon device button instead of camera controls

Comment: when i double press the beacon device button, camera starts and ready to capture. problem is that when again i double press the beacon device button the camera should capture the scene and save the the photo without using any built in controls of camera